# Jmeter- Need to download one time retrieving embedded resources for request

Tags: jmeter

My application contains home page and login page, each page contains 4 request
suppose 1 request contains 14 embedded resources, 2 request also contains same embedded resources + other additional resources, 3 request also smae
but here my question is how to download only one time in 1 request, if embedded resources are repeated for 2/3/4 request..i simply need to ignore or should take from cache..so that response time can be manager as same as in browser.

Thanks in advance for your help and appreciated
 Bhaskar

Comment: The Title can be updated to "Pick embedded resources from cache for Jmeter", also add some examples of what the emebedded resources are like js/css etc. It will help if request 1, request 2 is made into a numbered list.

Comment: thanks you, Mahesh..Actually my application contains lot of request..each request contains similar kind of embedded resources+other unique resources...but i need similar embedded resources should be download at once, remaining request needs simply ignore to download them and unique embedded resources to be downloaded...why because response time is very high as compared to browser

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan

- Without the HTTP Cache Manager JMeter will request all the embedded resources for each HTTP Request

  [image]
- And if you add the HTTP Cache Manager JMeter will execute the calls for the embedded resources only if the relevant images, scripts, styles, fonts, etc. are not present in cache, in other words JMeter will respect [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) and friends.

  [image]

This is exactly what real browsers do. Check out [Using the HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager) article for more detailed information if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dmitri, Actually it's downloading every time and calculating into response time hence it leads very high response time as compared to browser..I configured as you mentioned that adding https cache manager and selected retrieved embedded resources parallel download-6...but still it's not matching response time with browser..Please help how can i make it as close real to browser behaviour

Comment: No one will be able to help unless you share more information, i.e. request details. One thing I can think of is that your browser doesn't make actual requests and returns embedded resources from its cache. Try clearing your browser history **including cache** and retry the request in browser. Other reason could be that browser sends [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header therefore receives compressed response. You can achieve the same using [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for Clarifying the issue, i have added images in following google drive link https://drive.google.com/open?id=10UZfhWzme-o9ILSMyWcco-ePxhipxIxV

Comment: My application first Transaction-1,2,3,4,5 requests contain lot of embedded resources within it....2nd transaction having 4 requests contain similar kind of embedded resources + additional embedded resources....but it's downloading all the time and counting the time in everywhere. please have a look at screen shots and you get to know and please let me know how to configure effectively...Thanks a lot for your help!!1

Comment: Hi Dimtri, here is the code JMX file..https://drive.google.com/open?id=18iWX36mBsQkASW9BPdyy0OnqvqZm_ujA                      I see the big difference in browser and jmeter when I run them.please suggest how to configure to simulate to real browser and similar response times in both jmeter and browser, Thank you so much for your effort to debug this issue

Comment: From what I can see the majority of your requests contain [`ajax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), it means that in real browser they're executed asynchronously and in your JMeter scripts these requests are sequential. Consider moving them under [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) - this way JMeter will execute these AJAX calls in parallel like real browser does. You can install Parallel Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Dmitri..i will do that and let you know once it's done

Comment: Thanks again Dmitri for you wonderful suggestion to debug my script, now i got huge difference in my response time after i changed it to Parallel Controller as you suggested,Please review my updated scripts attached https://drive.google.com/open?id=17B8-SfMoJyazZ8V4wPnnKbP6j17TP42v     if i need it to change anything to make more real browser behaviour.